# Can a PHP function accept an unlimited number of parameters?

Tags: php, function, arguments

In PHP there are functions like `unset()` that support any number of parameter we throw at them.

I want to create a similar function that is capable of accepting any number of parameters and process them all.

Any idea, how to do this?

Comment: If you intend to do more research on the matter in the future, the term you're looking for is [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). The linked Wikipedia article even includes an example for PHP.

Comment: If you think there is a chance the functions will change in the future, you may want to use string variables with `parse_str`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In PHP, use the function `func_get_args` to get all passed arguments.

```
<?php
function myfunc(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg)
      echo $arg."/n";
}

myfunc('hello', 'world', '.');
?>
```

An alternative is to pass an array of variables to your function, so you don't have to work with things like `$arg[2];` and instead can use `$args['myvar'];` or rewmember what order things are passed in. It is also infinitely expandable which means you can add new variables later without having to change what you've already coded.

```
<?php
function myfunc($args){
    while(list($var, $value)=each($args))
      echo $var.' '.$value."/n";
}

myfunc(array('first'=>'hello', 'second'=>'world', '.'));
?>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use these functions from within your function scope:

- func_get_arg()
- func_get_args()
- func_num_args()

Some examples:

```
foreach (func_get_args() as $arg)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

```
for ($i = 0, $total = func_num_args(); $i < $total; $i++)
{
    $arg = func_get_arg($i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have PHP 5.6+ , then you can use

```
function sum(...$numbers)
```

[functions.variable-arg-list](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Answer (score 4):

You will have 3 functions at your disposal to work with this. Have the function declaration like:

```
function foo()
{
    /* Code here */
}
```

### Functions you can use are as follows

**[func_num_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)**
Which returns the amount of arguments that have been passed to the array

**[func_get_arg($index)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php)**
Which returns the value of the argument at the specified index

**[func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)**
Which returns an array of arguments provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) inside your function to parse any number of passed parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.6 or later version, argument lists may include the **`...`** token to denote that the function accepts a variable number of arguments. The arguments will be passed into the given variable as an array; Simply  Using **`...`** you can access unlimited variable arguments.

**for example:**

```
<?php
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $sum += $n;
    }
    return $sum ;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
?>
```

If you are using **PHP version <= 5.5** then you can access unlimited parameterusing the [func_num_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php), [func_get_arg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php), and [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) functions.

Answer (score 1):

php7 provides an easy way of `passing and catching unlimited parameters` to a function by using *ellipses* right before the *parameter name* in the function definition. Following is an example demonstrating the same:

```
<?php
function print_names(...$names){
  foreach($names AS $name) echo "The name is: <b>$name</b>.\n";
}
print_names(
  "Superman",
  "Ironman",
  "Spiderman",
  "HULK",
  "Thor",
  "Captain America",
  "Batman"
);
```

Credits: http://dwellupper.io/post/5/passing-unlimited-parameters-to-functions-in-php7

Comment: Given reference is incorrect. This was first introduced in PHP 5.6 https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list