# Php writing a function with unknown parameters?

Tags: php

How would I go about writing a function in php with an unknown number of parameters, for example

```
function echoData (parameter1, parameter2,) {
    //do something
}
```

But when you call the function you can use:

```
echoData('hello', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello'4);
```

So that more parameters can be sent as the number of parameters will be unknown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function with unlimited number of parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577383/php-function-with-unlimited-number-of-parameters) and [Can a PHP function accept an unlimited number of parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078454/can-a-php-function-accept-an-unlimited-number-of-parameters)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

```
function echoData(){
    $args = func_get_args();
}
```

Be aware that while you can do it, you shouldn't define any arguments in the function declaration if you are going to use func_get_args() - simply because it gets very confusing if/when any of the defined arguments are omitted

Similar functions about arguments

- func_get_arg()
- func_get_args()
- func_num_args()

Comment: Be aware that while you can do it, you shouldn't define any arguments in the function declaration if you are going to use `func_get_args()` - simply because it gets very confusing if/when any of the defined arguments are omitted.

Comment: @Dave: Nice catch. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 18):

Just for those who found this thread on Google.

[In PHP 5.6 and above you can use `...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) to specify the unknown number of parameters:

```
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}

echo sum(1, 2, 3, 4); // 10
```

`$numbers` is an array of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

use func_get_args() to retrieve an array of all parameters like that:

```
$args = func_get_args();
```

You can then use the array or iterate over it, whatever suits your use-case best.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an array:

```
<?php    
function example($args = array())
{
    if ( isset ( $args["arg1"] ) )
        echo "Arg1!";
}

example(array("arg1"=>"val", "arg2"=>"val"));
```