# Having issue with PHP class

Tags: php, arrays, oop, class

My PHP class looks like that.

```
 <?php
class htmlize {

    protected $base_dir;

    public function __construct( $base_dir = 'core/code/js/' )
    {
        $this->base_dir = $base_dir;
    }

    public function gimme_js_link ($list, $folder = '')
    {
        if(is_array($list)) {
        $links=array();
        foreach ($list as $name)
        {
            $links[]=$this->make_js_link ($name, $folder);
        }
        print_r ($links);
        }
        else {echo $this->make_js_link ($list, $folder);}
     }

     protected function make_js_link ($name, $folder)
     {
         $dir = $this->base_dir . $folder . '/';
         return '<script src="' . $dir . $name . '.js"></script>';
     }

  }

?>
```

Calling it like that

```
<? $js= new htmlize(); $js->gimme_js_link('jquery', 'libs'); ?>
```

The question is how can i get work this class either for array like `'jquery, ... , ...'` or for single element for ex `'jquery'`? Currently I made changes to `gimme_js_link` method: it checks `$list`variable whether it's array or not before processing.

But i feel that there must be more effective way, and we can shorten the code.  Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't think there is a more effective way -- you've done it correctly by checking `is_array()` and iterating over it if it is an array, or performing the single action if not.  Looks just fine to me :)

Comment: will `echo $js->gimme_js_link('jquery, ...', 'libs'); ?>` work for arrays too?

Comment: i need to implode the comma seperated js files before processing

Comment: You can't echo it, since it returns an array From here it looks like you've coded it correctly. Just try:`print_r($js->gimme_js_link(array('jquery', 'somethingelse'), 'libs');`

Comment: In other words, you need to pass in an array, _not a comma-separated list_

Comment: Getting output `<script src="core/code/js/libs/jquery, japss.js"></script>` when calling like that `$js->gimme_js_link('jquery, japss', 'libs');` . Actually result must be like that `<script src="core/code/js/libs/jquery.js"></script> <script src="core/code/js/libs/japss.js"></script>`

Comment: and how to modify this function to process comma seperated list?

Comment: See my comment about print_r(). You can't call it with a comma-separated list. Must pass it an array to begin with.

Comment: @Michael take a look at my updated question. I've made changes: now I'm using `print_r(...)` in case array and `echo` in case single. The problem is how can I process comma seperated list: I mean call will look like that `<? $js= new htmlize(); $js->gimme_js_link('jquery, something else, smth2, ...', 'libs'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took out the class properties so it can be run on [codepad](http://codepad.org/bc2RrDRK) quickly.

```
<?php
function gimme_js_link( $list, $folder = '')
{
    $list = explode( ',', $list);
    $links = array();
    foreach( $list as $name)
    {
        $links[] = make_js_link( trim( $name), $folder);
    }
    echo implode( '', $links);
} 

function make_js_link ($name, $folder)
{
    $dir = $folder . '/';
    return '<script src="' . $dir . $name . '.js"></script>';
}

gimme_js_link( 'jquery, functions, files', 'libs');
echo "\n";
gimme_js_link( 'jquery', 'libs');
```

**Output:**

```
<script src="libs/jquery.js"></script><script src="libs/functions.js"></script><script src="libs/files.js"></script>
<script src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: can't get it work within class. Getting error message : `Call to undefined function make_js_link() `

Answer (score 1):

It is usually done this way:

```
if(!is_array($input))
    $input = array($input);
```

For your string thingy you would have to code some function explicitly, that converts it into an array. I suggest to check via some regex if its a string of a list and if so, convert it into an array using a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have coded it rightly, just when you call the gimme_js_link() function, pass the 1st argument as an array whether you have a single list item or multiple items. Doing so you can skip the array checking part in your code. Refer the modified call to the function:

```
<? $js= new htmlize(); $js->gimme_js_link(array('jquery'), 'libs'); //for single list item. ?> 
<? $js= new htmlize(); $js->gimme_js_link(array('jquery','custom_script','another_script'), 'libs'); //for multiple list items ?>
```

If you call this way, you can skip the array checking part in your code and process the $list variable with the foreach loop directly.

What you want is a feature called **variable arguments**. Where you can specify a parameter is going to accept multiple arguments. Since PHP doesn't have the variable argument feature like there is one in Java (you can refer [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for a java example), array is the way to achieve this in php.

Comment: +1 because I like the consistency of this method the most. This how I usually handle these types of situations, I tend to avoid CSVs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Although the array solution is not too bad, [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) seems to be what you are looking for.

Also, please take a look at this [discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146999/php-writing-a-function-with-unknown-parameters)

Comment: take a look at comments please

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do, but I would highly discourage such a pattern. It's not easy to understand what the syntax is without giving a rather large description in the docblock. Also it's just plain wrong.

```
<?php

class htmlize
{
    public function gimme_js_link()
    {
        if (2 > func_num_args())
        {
            // Throw an exception if argument count is incorrect
            throw new BadMethodCallException('Method needs at least one library file to load and a directory to load it from.');
        }

        $list = func_get_args();
        $dir = array_pop($list);

        foreach ($list as $item)
        {
            // Load $item from $dir
        }
    }
}
```